# How to pass compiler options during Linux kernel compilation?

Tags: linux-kernel, build-system

For *reasons*, I need to compile the Linux kernel (currently 4.7.10) passing some simple and innocent additional command line options (e.g. `-pipe -Wsomething` etc) to the C compiler.

How do I do it?

More specifically, how do I enforce these compiler flags during plain `make` as well as during `make menuconfig` and similar, i.e. so that they are always passed to the C compiler whenever the latter is executed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Linux kernel's makefile:

```
# Add any arch overrides and user supplied CPPFLAGS, AFLAGS and CFLAGS as the
# last assignments
KBUILD_CPPFLAGS += $(ARCH_CPPFLAGS) $(KCPPFLAGS)
KBUILD_AFLAGS   += $(ARCH_AFLAGS)   $(KAFLAGS)
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += $(ARCH_CFLAGS)   $(KCFLAGS)
```

So, passing additional options for Kbuild uses usual environment/makefile variables but with `K` prefix:

```
make "KCFLAGS=-pipe -Wsomething"
```

Answer (score 6):

[Kbuild — The Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kbuild.html) provides a list of options,

- KCPPFLAGS

  Additional options to pass when preprocessing. The preprocessing options will be used in all cases where kbuild does preprocessing including building C files and assembler files.
- KAFLAGS

  Additional options to the assembler (for built-in and modules).
- AFLAGS_MODULE

  Additional assembler options for modules.
- AFLAGS_KERNEL

  Additional assembler options for built-in.
- KCFLAGS

  Additional options to the C compiler (for built-in and modules).
- CFLAGS_KERNEL

  Additional options for $(CC) when used to compile code that is compiled as built-in.
- CFLAGS_MODULE

  Additional module specific options to use for $(CC).
- LDFLAGS_MODULE

  Additional options used for $(LD) when linking modules.
- HOSTCFLAGS

  Additional flags to be passed to $(HOSTCC) when building host programs